How can I configure openapi-generator-cli to split client files into multiple dart libariaries?
My team has a large asp.net backend, with a Swagger spec generated using the swashbuckle package. We use openapi-generator-cli to build a dart client library that we use in our flutter application.
We're facing some major dart analyzer performance issues that result in 60-90 second hangs any time we trigger analysis on a class in our API package. I opened an issue on GitHub, and it was suggested that the cause of our analyzer performance issues is because of the large number of classes in our single API library.
Is it possible to configure our tooling to generate multiple API libraries that each contain fewer files? Solutions that only require modification to our openapi-generator-cli config would be preferable, since other projects use the same API and we'd like to avoid having to fix a million references there.
